# init() function call in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, declaration

I am following an online tutorial which presents me with the following (simplified) code:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    Node* next;
} Node;


int main(){
    Node *head;
    init(&head);
    return 0;
    
}
```

What is the purpose & functionality of the `init` function? I did not define it myself, however am struggling to find documentation online as well.

Comment: Doesn't the tutorial explain that? Not much of a tutorial if it doesn't. We can't tell you for sure what it does as we didn't write that. But likely it just does `*head = NULL;` to initialise an empty list.

Comment: init isn't in the standard library

Comment: looks like the tutorial has its own init function that initialises the head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters this declaration

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    Node* next;
} Node;
```

is incorrect. The name `Node` used in this data member declaration

```
    Node* next;
```

is undefined.

You need to write

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
```

As for your question then in this declaration

```
Node *head;
```

the pointer `head` has an indeterminate value because it is not initialized.

So it seems the function `init` just initializes the pointer. You need to pass the pointer by reference through a pointer to it. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the pointer `head`. Dereferencing the pointer to pointer you will get a direct access to the original pointer `head` that can be changed within the function. That is the function can look the following way

```
void init( Node **head )
{
    *head = NULL;
}
```

Pay attention to that you could just write in main

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

without a need to call the function `init`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `init` function is gonna be implemented in the next videos. I suppose that your teacher wants to use an init function to set some values if you create a new Node (or a struct in this case) to prevent <del>some easter eggs</del> undefined behaviour.